# how to update number without reloading

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a voting system in jquery. I have it where a user can vote up or if they change their mind vote down and it deducts from the upvote and puts it in on the down vote. But my problem is I cant get both numbers to refresh when a vote is selected so it just uses the original number instead of the updated number.

**Vote Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".vote").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name == 'up') {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html) {
                    parent.html(html);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "down_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html) {
                    parent.html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads LIMIT 9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $msg=$row['title'];
    $mes_id=$row['id'];
    $up=$row['up'];
    $down=$row['down'];
?>
<a href="" class="vote" id="
    <?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up">
    <?php echo $up; ?> up
</a>
<div class='down'>
    <a href="" class="vote" id="
        <?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down">
        <?php echo $down; ?>
    </a>
</div>
<div class='box2' >
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
</div>undefined</div>undefined
<?php } ?>
```

**The up_vote.php page..**

(down_vote.php is exactly the same as up_vote except it just changes up to down.)

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($_POST['id']) {
    $id     = $_POST['id'];
    $id     = mysql_escape_String($id);
    //Verify IP address in Voting_IP table
    $ip_sql = mysql_query("select ip from votes where img_id='$id' and ip='$ip'");
    $count  = mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

    if ($count == 0) {
        // Update Vote.
        $sql = "UPDATE uploads SET up=up+1 WHERE id='$id'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        // Insert IP address and Message Id in Voting_IP table.
        $sql_in = "insert into votes (id,img_id,ip,type) values ('','$id','$ip','up')";
        mysql_query($sql_in);
    } else {

        //if already voted change it..
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE img_id='$id' AND ip='$ip'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $vote_type = $row['type'];
        }
        if ($vote_type == 'down') {
            $up   = mysql_query("UPDATE uploads SET up=up+1 WHERE id='$id'");
            $down = mysql_query("UPDATE uploads SET down=down-1 WHERE id='$id'");
            $vote = mysql_query("UPDATE votes SET type=up WHERE img_id='$id' AND ip='$ip'");
        }
    }

    $result   = mysql_query("select up from uploads where id='$id'");
    $row      = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $up_value = $row['up'];
    echo $up_value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to use a jQuery version newer than `1.3.0`.

Comment: use jQuery 1.10 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: wouldn't you want it to use the original number? maybe im not understanding something. say it has 5 votes, you upvote 1 it has 6, you downvote 1 it should have 4 now, not go back down to 5, right?

Comment: Just lol, I just did a small experiment 1 hour ago about a voting system in http://spew.info/poll.php. Feel free to copy any of the code, thought it's only some jquery.

Comment: @chiliNUT when you upvote 1 the downvote number does not refresh and unless you manually refresh the page it will keep counting down from the last downvote number.

Comment: I'm concern with this: **`down_vote.php is exactly the same as up_vote except it just changes up to down`**. It'd be better to add an `if` to the existing code than to copy/paste the whole thing changing one small value.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but too long for a comment. This script:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $vote_type = $row['type'];
    }    
if ($vote_type == 'down') {
  /* ... */
  }
```

I don't think you need it like it is now. You are actually only using the last fetched row, not all of them. If that's your intention (because there's only one), then you don't need the `while()` at all. You could change it for:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$vote_type = $row['type'];
if ($vote_type == 'down') {
  /* ... */
  }
```

Furthermore, I'd recommend to change your code to PDO. It's more secure and mysql_* is deprecated.